# Windows service .Net core 3.1 not working after installing

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, service

I'm creating a windows service .net core 3.1 write log, I done it and run in debug and release mode ok but when I install it and start it in services.msc, the service is not working. Here is my code in worker.cs. Can someone help me? sorry for my bad English.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{

    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //When a mouse button is pressed
                Hook.GlobalEvents().MouseDown += Program_MouseDown;

                Application.Run(new ApplicationContext());

                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

                Thread updatedb = new Thread(UpdateDB);
                updatedb.Start();

                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            SaveMessage(e.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you add it to service?

Comment: i follow this link: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/07/creating-windows-services-in-net-core-part-3-the-net-core-worker-way/    and my testservice is listed in service.msc

Comment: To isolate one of the lines of code from an application type error, comment out the body of the method and see if it runs as a service then.  If it does, then it is one the functions within the method.  What account are you running this as?